# How to set session expiry time for mod_auth_openidc

Tags: openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc

We are using OpenID Connect on one of our applications, and implementing with Apache's mod_auth_openidc. Is there a way to set the expiry time of the session? Our current configuration looks like this:

```
    OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
    OIDCClientID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    OIDCClientSecret ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
    OIDCRedirectURI https://jZZZZZZZZ.com
    OIDCCryptoPassphrase <password>
    OIDCScope "openid email"
    <Location />
            AuthType openid-connect
            require valid-user
            Require claim hd:xxxxxx
   </Location>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set `OIDCSessionMaxDuration` as documented in the template `.conf` file https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/auth_openidc.conf#L529:

```
# Maximum duration of the application session
# When not defined the default is 8 hours (3600 * 8 seconds).
# When set to 0, the session duration will be set equal to the expiry time of the ID token.
# NB: this can be overridden on a per-OP basis in the .conf file using the key:
# "session_max_duration"
#OIDCSessionMaxDuration <seconds>
```

Comment: I have this configured, by still received `oidc_clean_expired_state_cookies` any ideas ?